# propel sql:insert throws error 'Unable to parse contents of sqldb.map'

Tags: php, orm, propel

I'm trying to build a project with Propel these days. I did the basic 'bookstore' tutorial on [propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html](http://propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html), but when I'm trying to finally insert the generated sql code via propel, to fill the database, the following error is thrown:

> [Exception] Unable to parse contents of "/sqldb.map".

*Unfortunately I've got no idea what went wrong; I followed the tutorial as precisely as possible.*

**Information about my installation and what I've done so far:**

**1)** Localhost installation (Mac OS 10.8.5) with PHP 5.4.27 (DOM Module, PDO and SPL enabled) and MySQL 5.6.19.

**2)** successfully parsed Composer.json with:

```
{
    "require": {
        "propel/propel": "~2.0@dev"
     },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["bookstoreDb/generated-classes/"]
     }
}
```

**3)** created a schema.xml with foreign keys, exactly like in the tutorial ([propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html](http://propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html)).

**4)** created a config file, propel.yaml, in subfolder 'conf', again like in the tutorial.

**5)** used the propel scripts to generate the necessary sql (`propel sql:build`), model (`propel model:build`) and configuration files (`propel config:convert`). The result of these commands are as indicated as in the tutorial.

**6)** created the database 'bookstore' successfully via terminal.

**7)** trying to insert the sql code via `propel sql:insert`. Now the error as described above is thrown:

> [Exception] Unable to parse contents of "/sqldb.map".

Here is the **index.php** of the project:

```
    // setup the autoloading
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
    // setup Propel
    require_once 'bookstoreDb/generated-conf/config.php';

    // Here I get the parse error: parse error in ../bookstore/bookstoreDb/generated-classes/Base/Author.php on line 138
    $author = new Author();
    $author->setFirstName('Jane');
    $author->setLastName('Austen');
    $author->save();
```

And here the **config.php**:

```
$serviceContainer = \Propel\Runtime\Propel::getServiceContainer();
$serviceContainer->checkVersion('2.0.0-dev');
$serviceContainer->setAdapterClass('bookstore', 'mysql');
$manager = new \Propel\Runtime\Connection\ConnectionManagerSingle();
$manager->setConfiguration(array (
  'classname' => 'Propel\\Runtime\\Connection\\ConnectionWrapper',
  'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bookstore',
  'user' => 'root',
  'password' => 'password',
  'attributes' =>
  array (
    'ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES' => false,
  ),
));
$manager->setName('bookstore');
$serviceContainer->setConnectionManager('bookstore', $manager);
$serviceContainer->setDefaultDatasource('bookstore');
```

Where may be the problem? And is there some other way to setup a basic project? I'd appreciate every help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted an issue for this: https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/issues/694

```
SqlBuildCommand uses configured sql-dir 
$manager->setWorkingDirectory($generatorConfig->getSection('paths')['sqlDir'])

SqlInsertCommand only uses the command line option 
$manager->setWorkingDirectory($input->getOption('sql-dir'));
```

adding `--sql-dir` option with correct sql dir to propel `sql:insert` does work

fix is submitted https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/pull/695 but not merged yet

Comment: Could you please clarify what directories should go in --sql-dir and --config-dir respectively ? Newbie here, so I am not sure about this. Thanks.